# SmartGWT imgbutton tooltip

Tags: java, html, smartgwt

I tried to add some tooltip text to `ImgButton`.

```
ImgButton imgButton = new ImgButton();
imgButton.setPrompt("text");
```

The problem is that rendered HTML-Image element contains "alt" attribute.

```
<img src="http://*/button.png" width="24" height="24" align="TEXTTOP" name="isc_Umain" alt="text" border="0" suppress="TRUE">
```

And this alt attribute works not properly in browsers like IE. It shows alt attribute content as a tooltip. So I've got two tooltips placed on each other.

[About Img tag and alt attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp)

I need to remove alt attribute from Img tag in HTML or I need to find out where this alt attribute is inserted while smartGWT constructing its components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem by overriding `getInnerHTML()` method and cutting down `alt="..."` if the browser is IE.

```
if (JS.isIE()) {
        imgButton = new ImgButton() {
            @Override
            public String getInnerHTML() {
                return super.getInnerHTML().replaceFirst("alt=\'[^\n]*?\'", "");
            }
        };
    } else {
        imgButton = new ImgButton();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This Bug has been introduced by SmartGWT 2.5. In previous version like 2.4 , it's working fine. The reason is . In SmartGWT 2.5 they have added support in "altText" to img.

But this problem has been resolved in latest version of SmartGWT